# Passing Database connection

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to open Database (Mongo) connection only once when I start application and share the same connection across the application. What am doing as part of app.js is

Creating connection

```
var dbConnection = mongoose.createConnection(config.database.address, config.database.dbName, config.database.port);
```

passing dbConnection in every route call

```
require('./services/MasterServices')(app , dbConnection);
```

Is it right approach or anything wrong here?

Comment: Does this code work for you, or are you having problems with it?

Comment: I do not have any problem, I'm asking if something wrong with the design or any better approach available there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `connect` function, which returns the default connection.

Just add `mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database');` whenever you need it.

See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: Hi, So I should create connection in app.js and use connect method (in different class) to get connection reference?

Answer (score 1):

if you have a module which looks after your db interaction, nodejs returns singleton objects for your module. This means you can create a connection in your module:

```
var connection mongoose. createConnection(); //only ever set up once. The first time it is required



exports.getConnection = function (cb){
  if(! connection) {
    connection =  mongoose.createConnection();
    cb(undefined,connection);
  }
  else cb(undefined, connection);
};
```

Just an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the connection into a file like "db.js", and then require it when necessary. So for example:

```
// db.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    config = require('./config.js');

module.exports = mongoose.createConnection(
    config.database.address, config.database.dbName, config.database.port);
```

And then in your routes, you might do something like:

```
// route.js
var db = require('./db.js');
```